# How to handle Project tango setPoseListenerFrames exception?

Tags: java, exception, google-project-tango

Sometimes I have keep getting this exception which I don't understand why it appear? or How to handle it so that the application will not terminate. And instead it has to try to reconnect again?

This is the exception I got:

```
E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable(uint32_t, const TangoCoordinateFramePair*, void (*)(void*, const TangoPoseData*), ...): Internal Error: setPoseListenerFrames failed.
I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable(uint32_t, const TangoCoordinateFramePair*, void (*)(void*, const TangoPoseData*), ...): Totally done connecting pose callback.
E/tango-client-api-jni: Error - TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable: -1
E/ObstacleDetectionActivity: Tango Exception! Try again!
                         com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoErrorException
                             at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.throwTangoExceptionIfNeeded(Tango.java:840)
                             at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.connectListener(Tango.java:391)
                             at com.tango.project.obstacledetectionapplication.ObstacleDetectionActivity.setTangoListeners(ObstacleDetectionActivity.java:291)
                             at com.tango.project.obstacledetectionapplication.ObstacleDetectionActivity.access$400(ObstacleDetectionActivity.java:51)
                             at com.tango.project.obstacledetectionapplication.ObstacleDetectionActivity$2.run(ObstacleDetectionActivity.java:235)
                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
I/Tango: com.google.tango: 11907
I/tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Getting config...
I/tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Done getting config.
I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Connecting to Tango...
I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Successfully connected to Tango.
I/tango_client_api: void TangoService_disconnect(): Disconnecting from Tango...
I/tango_client_api: void TangoService_disconnect(): Successfully disconnected     from Tango.
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Could you show me more code on how are you setting up the pose framepairs? The first line of log indicates that there's something wrong with either your framepairs or callbacks. Here is a good reference on how to connect it properly: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/blob/master/java_basic_examples/hello_motion_tracking/src/main/java/com/projecttango/examples/java/hellomotiontracking/HelloMotionTrackingActivity.java#L126

Comment: Thank you @jasonGuo, I used the default one without any changes. The one that is provided by Google Sample (Point cloud)